# What does the phrase "wistful settings" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a game's description:

> "This game’s **wistful settings** connected to the innovative idea of using real-world scale models."

The game uses both 3D technique and handmade photos. To make the visuals more attractive, developers have used real-scale models. I am not sure about the phrase "wistful settings" here.

Comment: It's rather unusual phrasing. ***Wistful*** essentially means *mournful / regretful*, particularly in the context of thinking about the past. But here it's probably more like *nostalgic / evocative* - of some hypothetical past "Golden Age", perhaps, that forms the ***setting** / backdrop / environment* within which the gameplay takes place.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is poor choice of word maybe?

Comment: @Neeku: I wouldn't say it's a "poor" choice of words. Just "unusual".

Comment: @FumbleFingers won't say it's a poor choice of words, but I will—and it's poor writing in general. The game's creators should have hired a better copywriter.

Comment: @Robusto: There are several instances in Google Books of something being a [*wistful setting for*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wistful+setting+for%22) / [*wistful backdrop to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wistful+backdrop+to%22) *[some narrative / spectacle / event / etc.]*. I'm not sure if the entire cited text is supposed to be a "sentence" or just a compound noun phrase, but I can't see anything inherently inappropriate about the specific two-word collocation being queried here. And I very much doubt it's aimed at non-native speakers who might struggle with it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [As Twain said](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3172/3172-h/3172-h.htm), "Use the right word, not its second cousin."

Comment: @Robusto: Indeed - but should Huck Finn have [***lighted out for the territory***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lighted+out+for+the+territory%22), rather than ***lit out**?* That one's always bothered me ever since I was a kid.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As always, Huck Finn  spoke the way a person of his background and location did and should have. There were few more careful ears in literature than Twain's.